# Run Simultaneous Methods In A Service Class Android

Tags: php, android, json, http, synchronization

I've been messing with a prob for past week over now ...

I need to run method defined in same class just after each other. They do connect to web-service and send huge JSON to it ...

What I'm doin' is ...

```
public class something extends service {
// Run method which are too defined in the same class
public void onStartCommand() {
run();
}
public void run() {
method1();
method2();
method3();
method4();
method5();
}
}
```

Also, in each method I'm using is storing over 250 JSONObjects in a single JSONArray ...
When I run the app, only a few objects of the array in the first method are read by the php script on web, later that it breaks! I can't figure out what it is the prob!

the php on the server to handle it is ...

```
<?php
    function write_contact($imei,$name,$phone) {
        $mysql = "config/mysql.php";
        require $mysql;
        mysql_select_db($db_name,$db_conn);
        $name_new = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
        $phone_new = mysql_real_escape_string($phone);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$imei."_contact WHERE `name`='$name_new' AND `phone`='$phone_new'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql,$db_conn);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){
            $new_sql = "INSERT INTO ".$imei."_contact (`name`,`phone`) VALUES ('$name_new','$phone_new')";
            $new_query = mysql_query($new_sql,$db_conn);
        }
    }
    $jArray = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jData = utf8_encode($jArray);
    $jSync = json_decode($jData);
    foreach($jSync as $jFetch) {
        $imei = $jFetch->imei;
        $name = $jFetch->name;
        $phone = $jFetch->phone;
        write_contact($imei,$name,$phone);
    }
?>
```

One of the Android method i'm executing ...

```
public void syncContact() {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
    JSONArray jContact = new JSONArray();
        String imei = getIMEI();
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            JSONObject contactSync = new JSONObject();
            try {
            contactSync.put("imei", imei);
            contactSync.put("name", name);
            contactSync.put("phone", phone);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Log.i("Error",ex.getMessage());
            }
        jContact.put(contactSync);
        }
        postSync("contactSync.php",jContact);
        phones.close();
    }

//Post Method

public HttpResponse postSync(String url, JSONObject jObject) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String base_url = "http://www.myurl.in/sync/";
        String post_url = base_url + url;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try{
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(post_url);
            post.setHeader("JSON",jObject.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObject.toString());    
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));  
            post.setEntity(se);  
            response = client.execute(post);
            Log.i("HTTP JSON",jObject.toString());
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Log.e("Error",ex.getMessage());
            }
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  
            System.out.println("HTTP post status = " + status);
            return response;
    }
```

Comment: i would suggest breaking this into two questions - one related to the threading and simultaneous method calls, and the other related to the json marshaling and network communication

Comment: also it is unclear if you want these methods to execute simultaneously or sequentially. the title of your question suggests simultaneously, but the description suggest one after the next sequentially. can you clarify?

Comment: Meant with breaks that when the app start syncing contacts to the server, nothing comes in to the mysql db or file (the way I used to check if it's a problem with the db) after 80 - 90 contacts ...

Comment: wrong word I chose, sequentially it is! F*ck my bad eng!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want to do threading, which is the right approach, but you aren't doing it correctly. Implementing a run() method is just one part of it. An object mustexplicitly implement the runnable interface, which defines the run() method you have. Then a runnable object must be passed to a Thread constructor and the resulting Thread object must be started via start().You can also define a Thread class and implement the run method within it. So there are a few ways to do this but in your case, the simplest will probably look something like this:

```
onStartCommand()
{
   new Thread()
   {
     public void run()
     {
        method1();
     }
   }.start();

   new Thread()
   {
     public void run()
     {
        method2();
     }
   }.start();
  ...
}
```

and so on. What this is doing is defining an Anonymous inner class (new Thread() { }) and calling start() on the object that is instantiated by the new Thread() constructor on that anonymous inner class. Each one of these anonymous inner classes spawns its own thread of execution, which will lead the JVM to execute the run() method in each of these. The run method will then call your method1(), method2() etc"worker" methods, and each of these will execute "simultaneously"

Comment: use an IntentService instead ! it uses a single thread but then it avoids having dozens of threads at once

Comment: he implied he wanted these methods to run simultaneously.. that would require multiple threads, each per method, no? from the IntentService api doc: All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

Comment: yes, but that would tend to a bad practice. multiple threads should be handled with a limit to the number of simultaneous thread, and a ThreadPool

Comment: true one must be mindful of the overhead of multiple threads and context switches. here though he described 5 method calls that are dong network transfer and so will have a fair amount of blocking and slow IO outside of the cpu. we are probably safe to expect at least two cores on the hardware, so 2 or 3 or more threads doing network transfers are acceptable

Comment: Well I am gon' do it speakingcode way! Mutiple thread for each method! But as other guys here say, What if i should run these method in an intentservice or service class?

Comment: Also I want to if there's any limitation of how much JSONObjects we can store in a JSONArray!

Comment: if you want them to be sequential, put them all in one thread, not each in a separate thread. as far as limitations on number objects, theoretically there is no limit, but there are practical constraints like the amount of memory available to your application, the reliability of the network as it transfers the data, and so on.

Comment: But i still doesn't seem to have got any help on why the f*ck it was breaking inna de mid of transfer! if it was a memory issue, I add that I'm testing it on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (ICS) device!

Comment: @speakingcode ... Thanks bro! It worked more awesome than money!